# connect remote database to local copy or WordPress

Tags: wordpress, remote-access

I am trying to link a local copy of wordpress to a remote database.

I keep getting a "Error establishing a database connection".

When I try to connect using mysqlworkbench with the same cedentialls I get a cannot connect to remote host and gives a 60061 error.

I really need to make progress on this I have wasted hours on it.

Comment: Does your database allow remote connections? It could be refusing because you're not on the local network.

Comment: I am using xaamp and the service is running. I have opened a port in my router firewall (3306), and I disabled my software firewall comodo on a temp basis - but still no joy